# import txt file to datagridview c#

Tags: c#, datagridview

hi i have txt file like this (email:password) and want to upload it into datagridview with 2 column

what i've done

```
bool flag = this.openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.Cancel;
        if (flag)
        {
            try
            {
                StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(openFileDialog1.FileName);
                dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
                string text = streamReader.ReadLine();
                string[] array = text.Split(new char[]
                {
                    ':'
                });
                for (text = streamReader.ReadLine(); text != null; text = streamReader.ReadLine())
                {
                    dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
                    for (int i = 0; i <= array.Count<string>() - 1; i++)
                    {
                        array = text.Split(new char[]
                        {
                            ':'
                        });
                       dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1].Cells[i].Value = array[i].ToString();
                    }
                }
                streamReader.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception var_7_106)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error+ err.Message ");
            }
        }
```

nothing imported in my datagridview

Comment: You'd be better off constructing an enumerable, like `DataTable`, from your data then just binding it to the grid. Databinding is almost always preferred to manipulating grid rows directly.

Comment: I see 3 `ReadLine()` calls. What you need to do is `While` not `for`.

Comment: can you edit it for me please ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code using a datatable

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;


namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            bool flag = this.openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.Cancel;
            if (flag)
            {
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                dt.Columns.Add("Col A", typeof(string));
                dt.Columns.Add("Col B", typeof(string));

                try
                {
                    StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(openFileDialog1.FileName);
                    dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
                    string text = "";
                    for (text = streamReader.ReadLine(); text != null; text = streamReader.ReadLine())
                    {
                        string[] array = text.Split(new char[] { ':' });
                        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(array);
                    }
                    streamReader.Close();
                }
                catch (Exception err)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Error" + err.Message );
                }

                dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
            }
        }
    }
}
```